# Loop runs multiple times after input before allowing input

Tags: c, loops, input, while-loop, scanf

So whenever I run this code, the code runs and prints out the results, then it runs again and prints some arbitirary results, and again, and again, then it lets me input for another loop. I could not find the error and tried searching online.

Help appreciated

```
while (x > 0)
{
    printf("Please enter your money and nickels (ex. $12.63 and 3 nickels). \nEnter 0 to end program:\n");
    scanf("%c %lf %s %d", &dollar, &money, &andWord, &nickel_input);

    if (dollar == '0')
    {
        printf("Thanks for using the program!");
        return 0;
    }

    money *= 100;

    money -= nickels * 5;

    quarters = (money / 25);
    money -= quarters * 25;

    dimes = (money / 10);
    money -= dimes * 10;

    nickels = (money / 5);
    money -= nickels * 5;

    pennies = (money / 1);
    money -= pennies * 1;

    coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

    nickels += nickel_input;

    printf("The fewest number of coins that you could have is %d:\n", coins);
    printf("# quarters: %d\n", quarters);
    printf("# dimes: %d\n", dimes);
    printf("# nickels: %d\n", nickels);
    printf("# pennies: %d\n\n", pennies);
}
```

By the way, this is just an excerpt from the code if you didn't know.

Comment: The program doesn't see your input until you hit return, but your scanf doesn't eat the return, so there's more input left for a second call to scanf. You might want to check the scanf return value.

Comment: @ArlieStephens so how would I scanf the return? using a char?

Comment: `scanf("%c %lf %s ,,,` --> `scanf(" %c %lf %s ...`  (add space)

Comment: Using floating point is challenging.  Better to move to integer math with `long imoney = round( money * 100);` and use `imoney` where`money` was used.

Comment: @chux the space didn't really do anything, and there is nothing wrong with the first calculations, it is just that it loops 2 more times before it finally prompts me to input values

Comment: @ArlieStephens is there a way to trash the input so I won't have to deal with that?

Comment: Best way to avoid trash on the input is to read a line with `fgets` and then parse the line with `sscanf`. Be sure to check the return value from both functions. `fgets` can return NULL, `sscanf` returns the number of successful conversions, which should be 4 in your case.

Comment: Your loop condition is `x>0`, but where do you update `x`?

Comment: why you want to use only one `scanf`. Use two instead; first to take input for money `scanf("%lf",&money);` and second to take for nickels `scanf("%d",&nickel_input);`. It'll be easier for user to enter the values.

Comment: @saloomi2012 - user3886109 gave the answer I would have, if I'd been online at the time.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks that worked, put it in an answer so i can choose it

Comment: @saloomi2012 I'm glad that worked for you. I copied it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to avoid situations where `scanf` leaves trash on the input is to read a line with `fgets` and then parse the line with `sscanf`. Be sure to check the return value from both functions. `fgets` will return NULL if the end-of-file is reached. `sscanf` returns the number of successful conversions, which should be 4 in your case.